# How to set a NULL when entering NULL keeps the old value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure where it is able to update the 4 columns below as there are 4 parameters (1 parameter for each column with ClawbackID the only one that doesn't change).

Now there is no fixed amount of columns that can be updated, I may choose to update 1 column, or 3 columns or all 4 columns. So to reduce human error, I have a coalesce so that if the user enters in 'NULL' for a particular parameter whilst executing a procedure, the original amount stays.

Example for row 3 for 'ClawbackAmount', if I enter in NULL and execute, it will still display the 'ClawbackAmount' 900.54. Now the problem I have is that actually want to set this amount to 'NULL', but I don't want to lose the functionality that if I type in 'NULL' when executing my procedure that it keeps the old value.

My question is that is there a way or an idea you can think of where I type in NULL then the default values stays but if I type in something like '' then it will default to 'NULL'?

Or alternatively type in the word 'SAME' to keep the default value and then type in 'NULL' for a null value? Just ideas really to get around it?

Below is the code I have with the parameters included as they begin with @:

```
update clw
set clw.PaymentID = Coalesce(@PaymentID, clw.PaymentId)
,clw.ClawbackDate = Coalesce(@ClawbackDate, clw.ClawbackDate)
, clw.ClawbackPercent = Coalesce(@ClawbackPercent, clw.ClawbackPercent)
, clw.ClawbackAmount = Coalesce(@ClawbackAmount,clw.ClawbackAmount)
OUTPUT '[Fees].EBD.Clawback' 'TableName','ClawbackId', inserted.ClawbackId,  
Core.updXMLFragment('PaymentId', inserted.PaymentId, deleted.PaymentId) + 
Core.updXMLFragment('ClawbackDate', Convert(varchar(50),inserted.ClawbackDate, 112), Convert(varchar(50),deleted.ClawbackDate, 112)) +
Core.updXMLFragment('ClawbackPercent', inserted.ClawbackPercent, deleted.ClawbackPercent) +
Core.updXMLFragment('ClawbackAmount', inserted.ClawbackAmount, deleted.ClawbackAmount) 

    INTO @OutputList 
from [Fees].EBD.Clawback clw
Where 
ClawbackId = @ClawbackID
```

Below is the code for the execution as an example for row 3 if I want to make the desired change:

First Param is ClawbackID (this doesn't change but need it to know which row to manipulate.

Second Param is PaymentID which is NULL as want to keep the same

Third Param is Clawbackdate which is NULL as want to keep the same

Fourth Param is ClawbackPercent which needs to be 0.25

Last Param is ClawbackAmount which I need to set to NULL. This is an int field btw but leaving it NULL will keep the orginal amount displayed.

```
exec SupportAudit.BI.UpdateHotelClawback 28817, NULL, NULL, 0.25, NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally use some specific invalid value as an indicator the column should be set to NULL.  In the case of `ClawbackPercent` and `ClawbackAmount`, -1 seems like a good candidate.  The change would look like this:

```
...
, clw.ClawbackPercent = NullIf(Coalesce(@ClawbackPercent, clw.ClawbackPercent), -1)
, clw.ClawbackAmount = NullIf(Coalesce(@ClawbackAmount,clw.ClawbackAmount), -1)
...
```

For string parameters, `''` (the empty string) might be an appropriate choice.

Comment: Coalesce is _how_ NULL means "Leave as is"; my suggestion keeps that functionality.

Comment: Using Coalesce as the first parameter in a NullIf is genius to accomplish this.  Recognize that there may be SQL Server and LINQ version requirements for this to work in all situations.  ( note I  deleted a previous comment that read 180 degrees backwards from what I meant)

Comment: Thank you very much